# In android the first fragment is not working properly

Tags: android, fragment

I have two fragments, the first fragment is calling the methods as the app starts and the second fragment's visibility is off so when the user is focusing on the second fragment the methods of the second fragment is getting called. But now if the user comes back to the first fragment and there is a change in the data in the first fragment, then the methods for the first fragment is not called and hence the change is not reflected. How to solve this problem?

The two fragments code are:`

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";
Context c;
String user_name,password;
MaterialSearchView materialSearchView;
String url = null;

RecyclerView rv1;
TableLayout tabLayout;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment,container,false);

    tabLayout=(TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    final TableLayout tabLayout1=(TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    final TableLayout tabLayout2=(TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout2);

    materialSearchView = (MaterialSearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("postman", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_name=sharedPreferences.getString("username","nothing");
    password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","nothing");

    rv1 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecycler1);




    rv1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
    rv1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    Download2 d2 = new Download2(getActivity(),url,rv1,user_name,password,tabLayout,materialSearchView);



    d2.execute();


    return view;
}
}
```

The other fragment code is :

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Tab3Fragment";

String user_name,password;
Context c;
MaterialSearchView materialSearchView3;
RecyclerView rv, rv1;
TableLayout tabLayout1 , tabLayout;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setUserVisibleHint(false);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment,container,false);


    tabLayout1=(TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);


    materialSearchView3 = (MaterialSearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("postman", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_name=sharedPreferences.getString("username","nothing");
    password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","nothing");

    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecycler);


    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
    rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    return view;
}

@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    if(menuVisible)
    {
        Download3 d3 = new Download3(getActivity(),url,rv,user_name,password,tabLayout1, materialSearchView3);
        d3.execute();
    }

  }
 }


public class Download2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>
{
    Context c;
    RecyclerView rv;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String user_name,password;
    MaterialSearchView materialSearchView;


    public Download2(Context c, String url, RecyclerView rv, String user_name, String password, TableLayout tabLayout, MaterialSearchView materialSearchView)
    {
        this.c=c;
        this.rv=rv;
        this.user_name=user_name;
        this.password=password;
        this.materialSearchView=materialSearchView;
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String data=this.downloadData();
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPostExecute(final String data)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(data);

        if(data!=null)
        {

            materialSearchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSearchViewShown() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchViewClosed() {

                    Parser p=new Parser(c,data,rv);
                    p.execute();
                }
            });

            materialSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                Toast.makeText(c, "in down2 "+newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(newText!=null && !newText.isEmpty())
                    {
                        ParserFilter pf = new ParserFilter(c,data,rv,newText);
                        pf.execute();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Parser p=new Parser(c,data,rv);
                        p.execute();
                    }
                    return true;

                }
            });
         }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Parser p=new Parser(c,data,rv);
        p.execute();
    }

    private String downloadData()
    {
        InputStream is=null;
        String line=null;



        try{

            ngroklinks lnk=new ngroklinks();

            URL url2 = new URL(lnk.players());
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line1="";
            while((line1 = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line1;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();


            return result;



        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(is!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return  null;
    }
}

public class FragmentControl extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public FragmentControl(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                Tab1Fragment tablFragment = new Tab1Fragment();
                return tablFragment;
            case 1:
                Tab3Fragment tab3Fragment = new Tab3Fragment();
                return tab3Fragment;
            /*case 2:
                Tab3Fragment tab3Fragment = new Tab3Fragment();
                return tab3Fragment;*/
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0 :
                return "Delivering";
            case 1 :
                return "Postponed";
           /* case 2 :
                return "Postponed";*/
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code or at least part where you think is the issue

Comment: What is `Download` class? And where do you saving values into `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: This fragment gets loaded after the login page, so the username and password from that activity are stored in the sharedPreferences

Comment: How user is switching between fragments?

Comment: I am doing in tab layout. The FragmentControl class is calling the fragments.The code of that has been attached.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code, so we can find what is wrong.

In the other hand, you should check this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNpWGI_hGGg

I suggest you to check his code and find what differ from yours.

Comment: Sir, I have posted the code. My question is when the user focuses in the first fragment from the second one, how the method downlod2 can be called?